# Using an iterator to print a set implemented by a separate chaining hash table

Tags: java, iterator, set, hashtable, tostring

I'm creating an implementation of a set in Java using separate chaining with a hash table. Currently, I am just trying to add 100 random integers to the table, and then use a self-built iterator in my own implementation of toString to print the table contents. I have confirmed with the debugger that my 100 ints get added to the table, but I am confused as to where my code goes wrong with printing.

The current output I get from my toString is just a single int inside curly braces, like so: {59, }.

I have gone through the debugger a few times step by step and cannot figure out of the issue is with my iterator, toString, or a combination of both. Here is the class below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MySet {
// implements a set using a separate chaining hash table
    private class Node {
        private Integer element;
        private Node next;
        private Node(Integer e, Node n) {
            element = e;
            next = n;
        }
    }

private Node table[]; //an array of linked list
private int lastHash; //last hash value used
private int tableSize; //current number of lists in the table
private int numElements; //number of elements in the set

private final int primes[] = {7, 23, 59, 131, 271, 563, 1171,
        2083, 4441, 8839, 16319, 32467,
        65701, 131413, 263983, 528991};

private int primeIndex; //last prime used

private int nextPrime(int p) {
    //finds the next prime from the list above
    //used for resizing and the initial size
    while (primes[primeIndex] <= p)
        primeIndex++;
    return primes[primeIndex];
}

public MySet(int s) {
    //s is a hint for the initial size
    primeIndex = 0;
    tableSize = nextPrime(s);
    //table is an array of nodes
    table = new Node[tableSize];
    numElements = 0;
}

private void resize() {
    //"double" the table size and reinsert the values stored in the
    //current table. the table size should remain prime
    int oldTableSize = tableSize;
    Node oldTable[] = table;
    tableSize = nextPrime(oldTableSize);
    table = new Node[tableSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < oldTableSize; i++) {
        Node temp = oldTable[i];
        while (temp != null) {
            int h = hash(temp.element);
            Node tempNext = temp.next;
            Node temp1 = table[h];
            table[h] = temp;
            table[h].next = temp1;
            temp = tempNext;
        }
    }
}

private int hash(Integer k) {
    //return the hash function value for k
    return Math.abs(k.hashCode() % tableSize);
}

public boolean find(Integer e) {
    //returns true when e is in the set, otherwise returns false
    lastHash = hash(e); //remember the last hash value used
    //this can be useful in methods that call find
    Node temp = table[lastHash];
    while (temp != null) {
        if (temp.element.equals(e)) return true;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    return false;
}

public void addElement(Integer e) {
    //if e is not in the set add e to the set otherwise the set does not change
    if(find(e)) {
        return;
    }
    //add e to the set
    int index = hash(e);
    if(table[index] == null) {
        table[index] = new Node(e, null);
    } else if(table[index].next == null) {
        table[index].next = new Node(e, null);
    } else {
        Node temp = table[index];
        while(temp.next != null) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        Node newNode = new Node(e, null);
        temp.next = newNode;
    }
    //if after adding the new element numElements > 2*tableSize then call resize
    numElements++;
    if(numElements > 2 * tableSize) {
        resize();
    }
    return;
}

//iterates through the entire table
public class MySetIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private Node curNode;
    int index;
    //implements an iterator for the set
    public MySetIterator() {
        curNode = table[0];
        index = 0;
    }
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return curNode.next != null;
    }
    public Integer next() {
        if(!hasNext()) {
            if(index > tableSize) {
                System.out.println("\n End of table!");
            }
            index++;
            curNode = table[index];
        }
        curNode = curNode.next;
        return curNode.element;

    }
    public void remove() {
        //not implemented
    }
}

public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    //returns an iterator for the set
    return new MySetIterator();
}

public String toString() {
    //returns a string representation for the set
    //the string representation of the set is { followed by a comma delimiter list of set
    //elements followed by a }. The string for the empty set is { }
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    if(numElements == 0) {
        return "{ }";
    }
    string.append("{ ");
    MySetIterator iterator = new MySetIterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        string.append(iterator.next() + ", ");
    }
    string.append(" }");
    String toReturn = string.toString();
    return toReturn;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    //Test driver
    MySet set = new MySet(0);
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        set.addElement(rand.nextInt(100));
    }
    System.out.println(set);
}
```

}

If someone could point out if I'm doing something wrong here that could be causing me issues, I would appreciate it. I have a feeling I am not using my iterator implementation correctly, but that doesn't necessarily mean my iterator is correct either. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What happens with an iterator is that its usage looks like:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  doSomething(iterator.next());
}
```

and as it stands, `hasNext()` returns false *before* `next()` has the chance to look for it.

Your `hasNext()` method will need to do all the work of finding the next entry, if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be doing anything in `next()` but returning a value and possibly pointing to the next potential one. `hasNext()` should simply return `true of false` if that points to a value.  If it returns `false` and someone calls `next()`, that is their problem, not yours.   And no need to call `hasNext` in your `next()` method.  Again, that's up to the user.  `hasNext()` should just check the appropriate variables to make certain the next value is available.  Presently, your `curNode.next` is returning null immediately.

It also appears that everywhere you call `new Node()`, the second argument is null.  Remember that multiple `ints` could hash to the same bucket.  So the buckets need to contain all of those `ints`.  One way to do this would be with a linked list but as far as I can tell, it doesn't appear that you are doing that.